# Video lecture series which covers CUDA and GPU related concepts from basics to advanced level

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, architecture, gpu

I am a master's student. During my bachelor's, our curriculum primarily focussed on CPU architecture. There are excellent textbooks and video lectures which deal with the CPU architecture in depth.

I was looking for a similar course for the GPU architecture in general. Considering NVIDIA GPUs, for example. (Given that NVIDIA is a beast in the GPU market, and comes up with many new optimizations now and then).

For example, a course that explains the basic architecture of the modern GPUs. The basics of CUDA runtime API. Then CUDA driver API. And then slowly moves on to advanced GPU topics like Unified Virtual Memory, CUDA streams, etc.

The official NVIDIA site has listings or blogs about the updates and features introduced. But honestly speaking, I find it difficult to understand them, because I do not have that good background.

Please can anyone guide me with a course (a video lecture series specifically, so that I can watch it at my own pace, I find starting with video lectures easier) so that after watching that, I am at ease reading the NVIDIA GPU blogs. Kickstart kind of course. But which goes into depth and also covers advanced topics.

I want to do research in the GPU subsystem. So, I need in-depth knowledge regarding the same.